# How to disable/remove salable quantity in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Please disable this module in `app/etc/config.php` file.

```
'Magento_Inventory' => 0
'Magento_InventoryAdminUi' => 0
'Magento_InventoryApi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryBundleProduct' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryCatalog' => 0,
'Magento_InventorySales' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryCatalogApi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryConfiguration' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryElasticsearch' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryImportExport' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryIndexer' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryProductAlert' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryReservations' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryReservationsApi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryCache' => 0,
'Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi' => 0,
'Magento_InventorySalesApi' => 0,
'Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi' => 0,
'Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryShipping' => 0,
'Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi' => 0,
'Magento_InventorySourceSelection' => 0,
'Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi' => 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please disable this module in `app/etc/config.php` file.

```
'Magento_Inventory' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryAdminUi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryApi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryBundleProduct' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryCatalog' => 0,
'Magento_InventorySales' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryCatalogApi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryConfiguration' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryElasticsearch' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryImportExport' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryIndexer' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryProductAlert' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryReservations' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryReservationsApi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryCache' => 0,
'Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi' => 0,
'Magento_InventorySalesApi' => 0,
'Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi' => 0,
'Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryShipping' => 0,
'Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi' => 0,
'Magento_InventorySourceSelection' => 0,
'Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi' => 0,
'Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi' => 0,
```

Comment: Hi @sathishraj after disabling salable qty on Magento 2 we have been one issue i.e on PDP & cart page system is allowing users to unlimited qty. which is not showing The requested qty is not an available error frontend.  can u help me on this issue

Answer (score 0):

**Please disable module using below commnd**

```
php bin/magento module:disable -f Magento_Inventory Magento_InventoryAdminUi Magento_InventoryApi Magento_InventoryBundleProduct Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalog Magento_InventorySales Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalogApi Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer Magento_InventoryConfiguration Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer Magento_InventoryImportExport Magento_InventoryIndexer Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi Magento_InventoryProductAlert Magento_InventoryReservations Magento_InventoryReservationsApi Magento_InventoryCache Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi Magento_InventorySalesApi Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi Magento_InventoryShipping Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi Magento_InventorySourceSelection Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_InventoryExportStockApi Magento_InventoryReservationCli Magento_InventoryExportStock Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator
```

**After run below commands**

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento i:rei
php bin/magento c:f
```