# Show Quantity instead of salable quantity on the product display page

Tags: magento2

I want to use **quantity** i.e 79 instead of **salable quantity** i.e 74. So, can anybody suggest how can I achieve this?

**Product Grid:**

[image]

**Product Display Page:**

[image]

Comment: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/inventory-product-stock-options.html

Answer (score 1):

1. The **quantity** and **salable quantity** are used for different purposes. The quantity is physical quantity such as products in the warehouse. The salable quantity is the online quantity to sell those products in the warehouse. (Reference: [Meetanshi - Magento 2 Salable Quantity vs Quantity](https://meetanshi.com/blog/magento-2-salable-quantity-vs-quantity/))
2. When an order is placed, the salable quantity is reduced and the quantity remains the same. It's more like booking, which we can cancel at any time unless the product is shipped. *(In default Magento, customer cannot cancel directly, admin can only cancel the order)*
3. Consider the below scenarios to understand the quantity and salable quantity.

- The product with the same quantity and salable quantity at initial. [image]
- The Customer placed an order with quantity 5 which will reduce only the salable quantity. If the customer reduces the quantity or cancels the order. In this stage, the salable quantity will be updated. *(In default Magento, customer cannot cancel directly, admin can only cancel the order)* [image]
- If the order is shipped. Then quantity will be reduced. [image]

4. If you want to show quantity instead of the salable quantity. Remember when your **salable quantity becomes 0** and **quantity remains 79** *(Let us consider nothing shipped yet)*. In this scenario, the products cannot be ordered and it will be confusing for a customer as `only 79 left` will be showing.
5. If still the order has to be placed then check [Backorders concept](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/inventory-backorders.html). but it will be confusing if we try to show the qty and accept backorders at same time.

In short, changing salable quantity value to quanity is not recommended way as each have it's own purpose. If you want to remove the whole salable quanity and keep it only quanity concept as Meganto1. Then that is different part. (Reference: [Disable salable qty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281400/how-to-disable-remove-salable-quantity-in-magento-2/317283) - as disabling is big conept try once in vanilla magento before performing on the production site)

Answer (score 0):

Salable quantity is the sum of available resources.

In Magento Current version....
The quantity of product does not decrease when a customer placed an order, instead salable quantity gets reduced while, The product quantity decreases when order shipping is completed.
When a customer places an order, in that case salable quantity is reduced, the quantity is not decreased even when the order is placed.

you can read more about salable quantity at here..
https://github.com/magento/inventory/wiki/Salable-Quantity-Calculation-and-Mechanism-of-Reservations

Or you can disable the setting from the admin panel than when your order will create then the stock will not Descrease.
Store->Catalog->Inventory->Stock Option

[image]